# Avarege of a photo and its brightness

Tags: image-processing

Assuming we have a blur image, $I$ , and by using a filter $f$, we get an improved image $I_1$ , the action for doing so is of course : $I_1=f \star I$

While $f$ is the following  filter:

$$f = \frac{1}{12} 
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & c & c & c & 0\\
b & 4a-b-2c & 4a-2c & 4a-b-2c & b\\
0 & c & c & c & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

$a$,$b$,$c$ are consts.

The question is: *what condition we need to assume on $a$, that the brightness of the image will be the same, aka the average of the image?*

One can suggest the we will demand the sum of elements  of $f$ will be 1. 
I don't understand why we suggest this, in order to keep the average of the image.

Comment: You can use *least square* or others optimization technique to find the $a$ that change less the brightness

Comment: And this is not a matrix I think that missing elements are 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question there is not a matrix because some elements are missing, I assume they are equal to $0$.

This solution in *MATLAB* should works:

```
syms a b c

f=1/12*[ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0, 0;
        0 , c , c , c , 0;
        b , 4*a-b-2*c , 4*a-2*c , 4*a-b-2*c , b;
        0 , c , c , c , 0;
        0 , 0 , 0 , 0, 0 ];

I=ones(size(f));
I1=f*I;
disp(mean(I1(:)));
```

the result is $a/5$ so the *mean* remains equal to $1$ with $a=5$

Also if your image will be different from an *ones* matrix the mean should be tend to the original if elements are $>0$. (I have not prove this so take this  empiric solution as is, also because with elements equal to 0 you can make mean dependents on the others variables).

EDIT:
I tried to add this code that i try with some fixed values for $b$ and $c$

```
% assume colors are from 0 to 1
v=zeros(1,30);
for i=1:30
    I=rand(size(f));
    I1=I*f;
    X=solve(mean(I1(:))==mean(I(:)),a);
    v(i)=(double(X));
end

disp(mean(v));
```

The mean of $v$ tends to $5$ with some $b$ and $c$ that I tried, like  expected.

So i think that $a=5$ is the right solution. But I have not time to search a formal prove. In general there is not a solution that depends only on $a$ and depends also on image data.